How to add custom claims to Azure AD users
I am developing a web application that uses Microsoft Azure AD (Entra) as identity server for single sign-in. So I have users defined in Azure AD.
Now I want to add additional properties or claims to each user, ie. I want to add these two claims to each user:
claim(property)Name = ExternalServiceUserId
claim(property)Name = ExternalServicePassword
So then I can add those informations in the Azure Portal to each user, and get them in my application by using Microsoft Graph API.
IE.
lets say that I have two users (User1, User2):
So I want to be able to add:
User1.ExternalServiceUserId = "someUserId"
User1.ExternalServicePAssword= "somePassword"

User2.ExternalServiceUserId = "someUserId2"
User2.ExternalServicePAssword= "somePassword2"

And I want to add these properties and their values through the Azure portal.
How to do so?

AFAIK it is not possible to add custom claims via Azure Portal. Instead use PowerShell and create claims and assign it to user. Check this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393221/how-to-set-up-custom-mapped-claims-to-azuread-app-registrations/76405502#76405502


Note that: AFAIK there is no way to create or assign custom claims to the user via Azure Portal.

You can create extensions for the application using Microsoft Graph API or PowerShell:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjID/extensionProperties
Content-type: application/json

{
    "name": "ExternalServiceUserId",
    "dataType": "String",
    "targetObjects": [
        "User"
    ]
}


Assign the value to the user:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN
Content-type: application/json

{
  "extension_XXX_ExternalServiceUserId": "333333"
}


Do the same with ExternalServicePAssword and assign to the user:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN
Content-type: application/json

{
  "extension_XXX_ExternalServicePAssword": "XXX"
}


Do the same with other user and assign the values to the User2.
Now configure optional claims in the application:

For sample, I generated access token via Postman:
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientId
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://ClientID/Claims.Read



When I decoded the access token, I am able to get the custom claims successfully:


Make sure to generate access token for the API as scope not for Microsoft Graph API.
Custom claims are displayed when token is generated by the API scope.


That does it. Thanks
